# whatis command Output redirection errors

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Do the following and it works

```
~$whatis `ls /bin`
stty (1)             - change and print terminal line settings

stty (2)             - unimplemented system calls

su (1)               - change user ID or become superuser

etc...
```

redirect the output to a file and I get this ?

```
~$ whatis `ls /bin` > blah

kmod: nothing appropriate.

ntfsck: nothing appropriate.
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments guy. my dumb self did not check to see if the stdout actually went to the blah file , which it did and i guess seeing the stderr threw me off. good reiteration of redirection of the streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` only redirects standard out (`stdout`), but when `whatis` cannot find information about a file it writes that to a different stream,  `stderr`.  You can redirect that as well with `2>` since `stderr` is file handle 2. You can redirect both stdout and stderr like `&>` or you could redirect stderr to stdout by doing`2>&1`

You can read all about redirection [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)

So in your example if you want all the errors as well as the success to end up in `blah` you could do

```
whatis `ls /bin` &> blah
```

or, using the alternate subshell syntax that's preferred these days:

```
whatis $(ls /bin) &> blah
```

though `/bin` isn't likely to have one though, be careful doing stuff like this.  The results of `ls /bin` will be subject to word splitting, so if any of the files there contain, say, spaces, they would be treated as different arguments to `whatis`.  This is why you're generally discouraged from parsing the output of `ls` (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) for a discussion of it)

you could do what you're trying differently like

```
find /bin -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec whatis {} + &> blah
```

which will look in `/bin` and not go deeper (like the glob) then find just files (the `type f` argument) and for each thing it finds it'll execute `whatis`, then do the same redirection we had talked about.

Answer (score 0):

***whatis***  searches  a set of database files containing short descriptions of system commands for keywords and displays the result on the
       standard output.  Only complete word matches are displayed.

**kmod: nothing appropriate.**  is a message tells that, it didnt find anything for kmod.

if you want to redirect all the output, then try this..

```
whatis $(ls /bin) > /tmp/a.txt
```

Comment: redirecting stdout is exactly what they did; I think you missed the part where `whatis` wrote to stderr, which wasn't captured by the redirection of stdout.